# can linux run without an RTC present on an embedded platform?

Tags: linux, embedded, real-time-clock

When running linux on an embedded platform, is a RTC required? In other words, does the kernel itself or drivers require an RTC to be present?

Comment: In the context of an "embedded system" this question is *not* about "*general computing hardware and software*" as suggested by the close votes, and I believe should stand.  A computer without an RTC may not be considered "general" but application specific, and the availability of time an important part of a software execution environment.  Consider this before voting to close.  If your objection is more specific than that, perhaps add a comment to help resolve any deficiencies in the question rather than just shutting it down with perhaps little understanding of embedded environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Raspberry Pi is an example of a Linux system with no RTC.  It gets time via NTP if it is connected to the internet, otherwise it must be set manually, but it runs nonetheless albeit with possibly incorrect time/date.

It is entirely possible to use a start-up script that prompts the user for time/date at start-up and set using the [`date`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/date) command, or to get time date from some other source such as a connected GPS or other networked time source.

If time is never set, it will start from 0000hrs 1 January 1970 at start-up, and increment normally while power is maintained and the system is not reset, so you can continue to use wall time to measure time *periods*, but not to determine actual time.  So for example tools such as *chron* will continue to work in some fashion.

Comment: is it possible to not have the kernel prompt for the time, and not have an RTC and ethernet connection? in the linux embedded application I 'm working on I don't care about the time.

Comment: RTC is not required by Linux. However the time wil be wrong if there is no internet connection - that's what happens when your system doesn't know the time. Downvote.

Comment: @Barny - The answer to the question is, "Yes Linux can run without an RTC". The fact that the system will then not have time is perhaps implicit. I am not sure what your objection to this answer is.

Comment: @b20000 : I originally stated that the RPi does prompt to time /date on start-up; I may be misremembering that or it may have changed. I have modified my answer to explain how a Linux system could do that.

Comment: thanks, all I want to do is have linux run without ever asking for the date or time and without needing an RTC :-) it's for an application where date/time is not necessary.

Comment: @b20000 : That's fine, the time will simply start from 0000hrs 1 January 1970 every time it is started up.  You won;t be prompted unless you set up your system to do that.

Comment: @clifford great, thanks, the 70s is a great time to live in forever.